# Mysql - find by name (not primary key)

Tags: mysql

If I use id = 2, which is the Primary Key - this succeeds.

If I use usr = admin, which is just a username - this fails: it returns false.

Database image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/av8sf.jpg

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = 10");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['usr']; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usr`, in your case, is a string with value `"admin"`. You need to let SQL know it's a string, so you need to escape it - Like so

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE usr = 'admin' ");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['usr'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote it

```
usr = 'admin'
```

Will work